# Google Webmaster Tool says I have malware, but it doesn't show the urls

Tags: google, malware, hijacked

So, I have a website hosting various freeware software for Windows (all clean): GWT says I have malware but it doesn't report any records:

[image]

I have already tried to submit a "request a review" but each time I do, it continues to say I have malware. What can I do?

Comment: You can scan your website using this tool : `https://sucuri.net/scanner/` It will show you page where malware placed.

Comment: it says it's clean

Comment: I see , then you should check each and every file of your site.

Comment: It would depend upon your OS which anti-virus you use, however, you should be using one good one and **not** on be on a shared server if you are accepting software uploads at all. For Linux, you can use ClamAV which seems to be the best out there. You will want to scan your entire harddrive and I recommend including rootkit just in case it is your server that has malware. Keep in mind that there is malware that is CMS aware and can randomly include bad code into pages or bad links to code on your site. So scan everything JIC to CYA (just in case/cover your @$$). It is likely a download.

Answer (score -2):

Download the samples Google provided, after verifying the code is clean, submit you website for review.